# Steiner tree subject to non-trivial constraint

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, approximation-algorithms

Given a edge-weighted transportation network modeled as a graph. A source node $s$ needs to send an object to a set of $k$ destination nodes $t_i$, $1\le i\le k$. For the transportation, $s$ needs to construct a tree rooted at itself. The particularity in my problem is that each branch node of the tree should make copies of the object (e.g., by using 3D printing) so as to send to multiple destinations, but the copying operation is not perfect. Specifically, if a branch node makes $c$ copies, the quality of each copy $q'=q\frac{2c+1}{3c}$, where $q$ denotes the quality of the object before copying and $q'$ denotes the quality of each copy after copying, given that the original quality of the object is initialized to $1$. Here the $c$ copies include the original one, whose quality also degrades to $q'$. My problem is to seek a min-weight steiner tree subject to that the copy recieved by each $t_i$ has quality $\ge \theta_i$, a threshold.

Comment: This is not a well-defined question. If you want an answer, you need to be more specific. Now, for example, an optimal solution would be for $s$ to make $k$ copies itself and send one to each $t_i$.

Comment: @domotorp Thank you for pointing out this. I have modified the problem.

Comment: How would behave the quality along a path from $s$ through all $t_i$'s? Is $c=1$ all along, or should $c$ be taken as $2$ on the $t_i$'s because the destination nodes are supposed to absorb one copy?

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier If a relay node is also a destination node, it should take $c=2$ as it needs a copy for itself.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused: do you assume that the transportation cost over an edge is the product of the edge weight and the number of objects transported over that edge (this would, indeed, make it sometimes *advantageous* to make copies at the branching points instead of transporting everything from the source) or you just restrict transportation over each edge to one object only (that will *force* copying).

Comment: @fedja Thank you for your comment. I don't see why there are multiple copies to send on a single edge. I was expecting that a branch node makes, say 3 copies, ans send them each on an edge. It will not send 3 copies via the same edge, otherwise it can delay the copying at the other end of the edge.

Comment: @lchen You may want have to make all copies at the source (where you can guarantee the quality $2/3$ regardless of the amount) and send them to terminals without any extra copying that may deteriorate the quality below the threshold. Think of a deep binary tree with the source at the root and terminals at the leaves. If you make 2 copies at every fork, then your quality comes down to $(5/6)^d$ where $d$ is the depth, which may become ridiculously small. The question is whether you are forced to do it or you just have to pay for it.

Comment: @fedja Good point. I wanted to avoid this trivial case. Now suppose sending a copy along an edge has a cost. We want to minimize total cost subject to quality constraint. Is this a meaningful problem? If yes, how to solve it?

Comment: @lchen OK, so let's think that the total transportation cost is as I said: the sum of edge weights times the number of items transported over the edge. The problem is non-trivial even if the graph is a weighted tree, so, perhaps, I would start there.

Comment: @lchen Also I'm curious: if, say, two copies arrive at a relay station and additional copies are made there, one can use one copy for copying or one can use both. Is it true that in the first case you downgrade the quality only of the used copy while in the second the degradation formula applies separately for two copying processes (so if you need to send out 100 copies, we can use $c=50$ on both arrivals (orsplit in any other way))?

Comment: @fedja In my problem, a node will not receive two copies as this is not an optimal strategy. But in general yes. In your example, if you receive 2 copies a and b, you can either copy a 100 times while keeping b or copy both 50 times. Seems that the first strategy is better.